# Is it good practice to use REST API in wp-admin plugin page?

Tags: ajax, rest-api

I wan to use REST API for saving and fetch setting of my plugin in wp-admin. Is it a good practice? Or is it better to use admin-ajax for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can and should totally do this in my opinion. Especially if you have a RESTful case. I personally only use admin-ajax for very simple things to almost no more.

Comment: Totally agree))